# how to go from String to method

Tags: java

I hope the title was understandable .

I have 4 functions :

`public void seta1(...);`

`public void seta2(...);`

`public void seta3(...);`

`public void seta4(...);`

Now the user gives me a String with the methods partial name ( say `String input = "a1"`).
Is there a way ( without using `case` option) to activate the correct method ?

something like : `(set+input)();`

Comment: Reflection? Method repository?

Comment: Command pattern (with factory) might be a useful pattern to consider.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/161005/994125) answer.

Comment: Introspection helps you get the properties of a bean and their corresponding read/write (getter/setters) methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you handle the possible exceptions, you can use Java Reflection API:

```
Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("set" + "a1");
method.invoke(obj, arg1,...);
```

Comment: `(...)` signifies that his method takes arguments, this code does not account for the possible arguments.

Comment: Your code will fail if there are args because you try are trying to invoke the methods with args but when you get the method, you don't specify the arg classes. Therefore, your code is invalid.

Comment: @JoshM The code is for just giving an idea, not solving the problem exactly, it is up to OP.

Answer (score 2):

**Introspection** is intended for that purpose (see [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html)).

```
//Here, I use Introspection to get the properties of the class.
PropertyDescriptor[] props = Introspector.getBeanInfo(YourClass.class).getPropertyDescriptors();

for(PropertyDescriptor p:props){
    //Among the properties, I want to get the one which name is a1.
    if(p.getName().equals("a1")){
        Method method  = p.getWriteMethod();
        //Now, you can execute the method by reflection.
    }
}
```

Note that **Introspection** and **Reflection** are 2 different things.

Comment: No, they aren't. Introspection uses reflection under the hood.

Comment: Conceptually, they are different but you are right, from the point of view of dependencies, Introspection is strongly linked to Reflection.

Comment: There is a difference: [Why is reflection called reflection instead of introspection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351577/why-is-reflection-called-reflection-instead-of-introspection) but it's more like introspection is part of reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection:

```
public void invoke(final String suffix, final Object... args) throws Exception{
    getClass().getDeclaredMethod("set" + suffix, argTypes(args)).invoke(this, args);
}

private Class[] argTypes(final Object... args){
    final Class[] types = new Class[args.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < types.length; i++)
        types[i] = args[i].getClass();
    return types;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

though it is little odd, possible with reflection. Try out
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html