# Using reflection to modify the structure of an object

Tags: java, reflection

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29):

> reflection is the ability of a computer program to examine and modify the structure and behavior (specifically the values, meta-data, properties and functions) of an object at runtime.

Can anyone give me a concrete example of modifying the structure of an object? I'm aware of the following example.

```
Object foo = Class.forName("complete.classpath.and.Foo").newInstance();
Method m = foo.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("hello", new Class<?>[0]);
m.invoke(foo);
```

Other ways to get the class and examine structures. But the questions is how modify is done?

Comment: Check out the `Field` and `Proxy` classes.

Comment: You can get a field and set its value to something different. What exactly is it you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, reflection is not fully supported as defined by the wikipedia.

Only `Field.setAccessible(true)` or `Method.setAccessible(true)` really modifies a class, and still it only changes security, not behaviour.

Frameworks like e.g. hibernate use this to add behaviour to a class by e.g. generating a subclass in bytecode that accesses private fields in the parent class.

Java is still a static typed language, unlike javascript where you can change any behaviour at runtime.

Comment: Really helpful, Thanks! So all others are just introspection(examination of structure)?

Comment: You can set field values via the reflection api, that's more than just introspection, but it's not a structural change.

Answer (score 2):

Just an additional hint since the previous answers and comments answer the question concerning reflection.
To really change the structur of a class and therefore its behaviour  during runtime look at Byte code instrumentaion and in this case javassist and asm libs. In any case this is not trivial task.

Additionally you might have a look at aspect programming technic, which enables you to enhance methods with some functionallity. Often used to introduce logging without the need to have a dependency of the logging classes within your class and also dont have the invocations of the logging methods between the problem related code.

Answer (score 2):

In English reflection means "mirror image".

So I'd disagree with the Wikipedia definition. For me, reflection is about runtime inspection of code, not manipulation.

In java, you can modify the bytecode at runtime using byte code manipulation. One well known library and in wide spread use is [CGLIB.](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: "For me, reflection is about runtime inspection of code, not manipulation." +1

Comment: So you mean reflection == introspection?

Comment: There is a lot of discussion on the exact meaning of the words even on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351577/why-is-reflection-called-reflection-instead-of-introspection 
In java, java.beans.Introspector class is uses to inspect the bean so it could be used by visual tools for example, so I'd use introspection in that context. For Bruce Eckel, reflection is  run-time class information (while RTTI is run-time type information).

Answer (score 1):

The only method in reflection (`java.lang.reflect`) to modify object's class behaviour is to change the accessibility flag of Constructor, Method and Field - `setAccessible`, whatever wiki says. Though there are libraries like http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Code_Engineering_Library for decomposing, modifying, and recomposing binary Java classes