# Java change the class filed name using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

If there is any way to change the field name of the new instance         **(foo)** by using java reflection.

```
    Class Foo {
    String filed1;
    int filed2;
    }
Foo foo= new Foo();
```

By creating a new instance of Foo, access the foo filed1 and change it to **hello**

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You can't write `foo.hello = "hello"`, it won't compile. Do you look for some dynamic data structure ? You should explain your use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using reflection to modify the structure of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817033/using-reflection-to-modify-the-structure-of-an-object)

Comment: Maybe you can change it at startup time only? without reflections then, but we still would need to know what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection is mostly about introspection, which does not involve manipulating a class. You can use byte code transformation to add a field to a class (look at tools like ASM or Javaassist.)